# Need some explanation over generators.

Tags: group-theory

I have this situation:

$S$ generates $G$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Then I have the condition that $\forall x \in S | xHx^{-1} \subseteq H$.

But this only makes sense if $e$, the identity is not an element of $S$. Otherwise $xHx^{-1}=H$.

But I thought that $e$ was always an element of $S$ if the later was the set of generators?!

To be clear the question is whether or not the identity is always an element of the set of generators. I think not, thinking about cyclic groups...

Comment: $\subseteq$ does not preclude $=$.

Comment: @user Yes but is $e$ always an element of $S$ or not necessarily?

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** $e$ need not be an element of $S$ if $S$ generates the group $G$. Consider the group $G:=\{e,x,x^{-1}\}$. $S:=\{x,x^{-1}\}$ generates $G$ because $x*x^{-1}=e.$ However, $e\not\in S$.